# Decoding JSON int into string

Tags: go

I have this simple JSON string where I want `user_id` to be converted into **string** when doing `json.Unmarshal`:

```
{"user_id": 344, "user_name": "shiki"}
```

I have tried this:

```
type User struct {
  Id       string `json:"user_id,int"`
  Username string `json:"user_name"`
}

func main() {
  input := `{"user_id": 344, "user_name": "shiki"}`
  user := User{}
  err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(input), &user)
  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }

  fmt.Println(user)
}
```

But I just get this error:

```
panic: json: cannot unmarshal number into Go value of type string
```

Playground link: http://play.golang.org/p/mAhKYiPDt0

Answer (score 67):

You can use the type [`json.Number`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Number) which is implemented as a `string`:

```
type User struct {
        Id       json.Number `json:"user_id"`
        Username string      `json:"user_name"`
}
```

Then you can simply [convert](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions) it in any other code:

```
stringNumber := string(userInstance.Id)
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/2BTtWKkt8ai

Comment: True. I am currently going with that option (using just `int`). I am however asking if there's a way to automatically convert it during decoding. It'll be very convenient.

Comment: Sorry - I am yet to write my own decoder (still new to Go). That said, it shouldn't be too hard. Googling custom unmarshal/decoder seems to throw up a few links.

Comment: OMG. *banging head against wall, table, threw laptop out window* I've been searching for why I can't convert a json longitude into float64 for hours (days?) cause the source uses empty "" strings when there was none (bad source).  So, it was up to me to make exceptional parsing for it.  This was insane. "cannot unmarshal number into string", "cannot unmarshal string into float64", "cannot unmarshal X into XX".  There is a "json.Number"?!?!  ARgh.  IT WORKED!  +10000

Comment: using `json.Number` works in sending POST data via http. But inside internal Structs I had to convert `8.0` into `"8"` is this okay ?

Comment: Sorry @STEEL without some context I'm not sure what you mean. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Is there any documentation on the `,Number` annotation?

Comment: @Crazometer no idea what @SimonWhitehead meant by that; it's non-standard and ignored by the standard `encoding/json` package (you can put any random text option in an otherwise reasonably formatted struct tag and it will *currently* do nothing, e.g. `json:"name",blahBlah_This_Is_Ignored`). I've edited it out of the answer to avoid confusion.

Comment: Errr, yeah not sure how that snuck in there. Thanks for the edit Dave!